# How to save and retrieve value or selection of a Check Box in Android shared preferences?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, spinner, shared

I am trying to save and retrieve information the user enters in a edit box and the selections made on check box. I have managed to get the edit box working but after several hours I still can't work out how to do it with the Checkbox.

This is for the Edit Box and it works fine to save the information.

```
editor.putString("saveName", name.getText().toString());
```

But this don't for Checkbox
    editor.putBoolean("saveChoice1", choice1.isChecked());

This is for the Edit Box and it works fine to read the information.

```
editor.putString("saveName", name.getText().toString());
```

But this doesn't for the Checkbox

```
choice1.setSelected(sharedPref.getBoolean("saveChoice1", false));
```

I have spent a lot of time doing this and would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Notice that you're calling `putInt()` with `"saveGender"` for the key, and calling `getInt()` with `"savedGender"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
editor.putInt("saveGender", (Integer) Gender.getSelectedItem());
```

with

```
editor.putInt("saveGender", (Integer) Gender.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

getSelectedItem() will return selected item text and getSelectedItemPosition() will return the position

Comment: Thanks that works, do you know how I can do it for the check box as well?